# Disable payment method in magento2?

Tags: onepage-checkout, magento2.2, php-7

How to  disable cash on delivery payment based on cod availability.
**etc/di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\Cashondelivery">
        <plugin name="cashondeliveryplugin" type="Xxx\Yyy\Plugin\Model\Cashondelivery" sortOrder="10" disabled="false" /> </type>
```

**Cashondelivery.php**

```
 public function aroundIsAvailable(\Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\Cashondelivery $subject, callable $proceed,$quote = null)
    {
        $result = $proceed($quote);
        $codAvailability = $this->_pincodeModel->isCODAvailable($quote->getShippingAddress()->getPostcode()) ? "yes" : "no";            
        if ($codAvailability == 'no') {
            return false;
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Its not working in frontend...Any modification in my code .....

Comment: <plugin name="cashondeliveryplugin" type="Xxx\Yyy\Plugin\Model\Cashondelivery" sortOrder="10" disabled="true" />  not working for you ? Run the setup upgrade again and check

Comment: make sure the disabled="true"   in your etc/di.xml file

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 0):

You tried wrong way, try following way:

**SR/Stackexchange/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Payment\Model\MethodList">
        <plugin name="cashondeliveryplugin_frontend" type="SR\Stackexchange\Plugin\Model\MethodList" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\Cashondelivery">
        <plugin name="cashondeliveryplugin" type="SR\Stackexchange\Plugin\Model\Cashondelivery" sortOrder="10" disabled="false" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**SR/Stackexchange/Plugin/Model/MethodList.php**

```
namespace SR\Stackexchange\Plugin\Model;

class MethodList
{
    public function afterGetAvailableMethods(
        \Magento\Payment\Model\MethodList $subject,
        $availableMethods,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface $quote = null
    ) {
        foreach ($availableMethods as $key => $method) {
            if($method->getCode() == 'cashondelivery') {
                $codAvailability = $this->_pincodeModel->isCODAvailable($quote->getShippingAddress()->getPostcode()) ? 'yes' : 'no';
                if ($codAvailability == 'no') {
                    unset($availableMethods[$key]);
                }
            }
        }

        return $availableMethods;
    }
}
```

**SR/Stackexchange/Plugin/Model/Cashondelivery.php**

```
namespace SR\Stackexchange\Plugin\Model;

class Cashondelivery
{
    public function aroundIsAvailable(
        \Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\Cashondelivery $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface $quote = null
    ) {
        $codAvailability = $this->_pincodeModel->isCODAvailable($quote->getShippingAddress()->getPostcode()) ? 'yes' : 'no';
        if ($codAvailability == 'no') {
            return false;
        }
        return $proceed($quote);;
    }
}
```

Comment: Its working on front end only ...but i need both on frontend and backend......

Comment: its global, so you can use it for both

Comment: Sorry this is only for frontend. I will come up with backend too.

Comment: Check updated answer

Comment: Yes, both use different way.

Comment: can i get front end and backend changes  on single file using aroundIsAvailable function....?

Comment: No way. Frontend not call aroundIsAvailable anymore. Frontend checkout is rest.

Comment: What is that? Which section?

Comment: Both function getting same quote...then... why..can u explain that

Comment: You should go with this two way. Frontend/admin always create quote for placing order. Frontend use rest for getting available payment method by \Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\Cashondelivery:: isActive where you have only storeId, so not possible to get postcode here But in admin go with \Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\Cashondelivery:: isAvailable. Make any sense?

Comment: Check this line https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Model/ShippingInformationManagement.php#L185

Comment: And then https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/app/code/Magento/Quote/Model/PaymentMethodManagement.php#L108

Comment: for backend->where to call isAvailable() method for showing available payment method list in core file

Comment: Check https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/app/code/Magento/Payment/Block/Form/Container.php#L156

Comment: Magento 1 => https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/302345/57334 any help thanks @SohelRana